# Images get stretched out using height: auto. What's the substitute for this?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have developed a website which works fine in the latest Chrome version 75.0.3770.142 while the old version doesn't render properly, i.e the images are stretched out vertically.

I have used `height:auto`. The same problem occurs in Opera, Safari and IE. The latest update of Mozilla tends to work fine. But the old version gives the same problem.

Please help me out. I have the parent element's height set to auto (same as the media query shown below) and I have used flexbox to center images.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 414px){
#firstsec{
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(aliali1.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  } 

  #firstsec h1{
   font-size: 34px;
   padding-bottom: 4px;
  }
  
  #firstsec #headerdesign img{
  padding-top: 30px;
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
  }
```

```html
<section id="firstsec" class="parallax col-12">
   <div id="headerdesign" class="d-flex justify-content-center col-12">
     <img class="col-12 hello" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnaKJ.png" alt="Cannot Load Image">
   </div>
   <div class="d-flex justify-content-center col-12 animated tada"><h1>“Hello this is Ali!"</br>I'm an Engineer & i like Designing</h1></div>

   <button class="button button4 animated flash"><a href="#secondsec">Check out my work !</a></button>
</section>
```

[image: headerdesign1]

Comment: it'd be better if you provide us the html code whic is responsive to view the image

Comment: I have added. Thanks!

Comment: your image path is incorrect please add live image path so we can help you out.

Comment: img probably is a flex element, so it has align-items property setted to stretch by default. try to overwrite this property [align-items](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-items/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add align-items:center property in your stylesheet to your existing bootstrap class property because by default its align-items:stretch. Example below;

```
.justify-content-center{
  align-items: center;
}
```

```
<div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Image has a width of 3980. Using height:auto, it will display the image in full height and scale the width (anchored, to 3980px). Have you tried to use

```
.hello{
  width:100%;
}
```

so that your image cannot be bigger than the viewport of the parent container?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions. I already found a solution. Checkout my answer!

Answer (score 0):

```css
img.col-12.hello {
  width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 414px){
  #firstsec{
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(aliali1.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
  } 

  #firstsec h1{
    font-size: 34px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
  }

  #firstsec #headerdesign img{
    padding-top: 30px;
    width:200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<section id="firstsec" class="parallax col-12">
   <div id="headerdesign" class="d-flex justify-content-center col-12">
     <img class="col-12 hello" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnaKJ.png" alt="Cannot Load Image">
   </div>
   <div class="d-flex justify-content-center col-12 animated tada"><h1>“Hello this is Ali!"</br>I'm an Engineer & i like Designing</h1></div>

   <button class="button button4 animated flash"><a href="#secondsec">Check out my work !</a></button>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your image class and call responsive class, and make sure you import all Bootstrap classes.

Comment: I think this provides an answer to the question.